# Smart CONVERT float to VARCHAR in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, varcharmax

I have the following code

```
DECLARE @m FLOAT=213456789.55
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='INSERT INTO Test VALUES('+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@m,1)+')'
EXEC(@sql)
```

but the result is `213456790` instead of `213456789.55`

When I try to write `CONVERT(VARCHAR,213456789.55,1)` it then returns `213456789.55` not `213456790`

How do I solve this?

**EDITS**

Declaring @m as Decimal like following `DECLARE @m DECIMAL(18,2)=213456789.55` solved the issue but I want to know if there is another solution for using float. Thanks

Comment: `CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @m)` should do it.

Comment: tried without success! It doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`STR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189527.aspx) instead of [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx). `STR` allows to specify number of decimal places to the right of the decimal point.

```
DECLARE @m FLOAT=213456789.55;
SELECT 
@m AS [Float]
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@m,0) AS Convert0
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@m,1) AS Convert1
,CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@m,2) AS Convert2
,LTRIM(STR(@m, 20, 2)) AS [Str]
```

**Result** (SQL Server 2008)

```
+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------+
|    Float     |   Convert0   |    Convert1    |        Convert2        |     Str      |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------+
| 213456789.55 | 2.13457e+008 | 2.1345679e+008 | 2.134567895500000e+008 | 213456789.55 |
+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------+
```

`CONVERT` always uses scientific notation for `float` types.

Comment: Thank you it works! Except when `@m =12456354213456789.55;`

Comment: [float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173773.aspx) has precision of 15 digits. So, when you assign `12456354213456789.55` to `float` variable the value is rounded. If you need more than 15 digits of precision, you have to use `decimal`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @m FLOAT=213456789.55
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)='INSERT INTO Test VALUES('+CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(@m AS MONEY),1)+')'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, time and effort BUT while this can work, it is not a not idea to change the `float` type into `money`. The goal was not to change the data type (other than varchar)